# How to serialize object to std::string using rapidjson (Implemented serialize)?

Tags: c++, json

How to serialize object to std::string using rapidjson ?
I have implemented

```
class Person{
public:
    std::string name;
    uint64 id; // uint64 is typedef

    template <typename Writer>
    void Serialize(Writer& writer) const {
        writer.StartObject();
        writer.String("name");
        writer.String(name);
        writer.String(("id"));
        writer.Uint64(id);
        writer.EndObject();
    }
     std::string serialize(){
        FileStream s(stdout);
        PrettyWriter<FileStream> writer(s);   
        Serialize(writer);
        return  ? /// There is a problem

    }
}
```

problem is in serialize function what to return ?

Answer (score 4):

Question is pretty old, in case you're still looking for answer, then here is the one as suggested by @Lightness Races in Orbit

```
class Person{
public:
    std::string name;
    uint64 id; // uint64 is typedef

    template <typename Writer>
    void Serialize(Writer& writer) const {
        writer.StartObject();
        writer.String("name");
        writer.String(name);
        writer.String(("id"));
        writer.Uint64(id);
        writer.EndObject();
    }
     std::string serialize(){
        StringBuffer s;
        Writer<StringBuffer> writer(s);
        Serialize(writer);
        return  s.GetString();
    }
}
```

You can also look at example code here: [simplewriter.cpp](https://github.com/miloyip/rapidjson/blob/master/example/simplewriter/simplewriter.cpp)

Answer (score 2):

Nothing. You already sent it to `stdout`.

If you don't want to stream the output to a file, don't use `FileStream`; use some other template argument to `PrettyWriter`, that stores and allows you to extract a string.

From a quick glance through the documentation, [`StringBuffer`](http://code.google.com/p/rapidjson/source/browse/trunk/include/rapidjson/stringbuffer.h) looks promising. It's a type alias for `GenericStringBuffer<UTF8<> >`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
std::string serialize() {
  GenericStringBuffer<UTF8<> > buffer;
  Writer<GenericStringBuffer<UTF8<> > > writer(buffer);

  Serialize(writer);

  return buffer.GetString();
}
```